# What did I do wrong? Trying to get user to enter numeric values for different variables

Tags: c, input, output, prompt

I am trying to figure out how I can make my program read what the user is typing in, such as a numeric value in this case but I'm having trouble. Here is what I put so far. The first part of the code is just a fake name and email address that just outputs my credentials (so that shouldn't matter).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
     printf("John Smith\n");
     printf("abc@abc.com\n");

     /* User must enter values in feet */
     int d;
     printf("Enter length for side a: \n");
     scanf(" %d");

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put your variable into the scanf:

```
scanf(" %d", &d);
printf("You entered %d\n", d);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now what if I have 5 more values that need to be entered? Should I do the same code as the one you showed me? Use %d too?

Answer (score 0):

To read a value from scanf you must give it the address of the variable using (&)

Like so:

```
scanf(" %d",&d);
```